# Import of PEM certificate chain and key to Java Keystore

Tags: java, keystore, client-certificates, pem, pkcs#12

I have a base-64 encoded PEM string which contains a certificate chain and private key. When I am trying to load the same in "JKS" type keystore its giving "java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format" error.

I also tried the same with "PKCS12" keystore and it gives the error "java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45"

```
String keyStorePassword = destination.get("keyStorePassword").get().toString();
String certificateContent = certificateObject.getContent(); //Base 64 encoded pem string
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); //KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
byte[] stream = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificateContent);
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream);
keyStore.load(input,keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
```

How can I import this into KeyStore? Any advice or hints are much welcome.

Comment: PEM is not a keystore format supported by Java. You can (1) use OpenSSL to _convert_ to PKCS12, which Java can read (except OpenSSL 3.0.0 up uses PKCS12 options that older versions of Java can't read, in that case use `openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy`) (2) use a program that handles PEM, like https://keystore-explorer.org (3) use https://www.BouncyCastle.org to read the PEM . Only (3) is now in scope for Stack, but there are hundreds of existing Qs and As from past years on all of these, just put 'convert PEM to Java' or 'read PEM in Java' or similar in the search box.